# Roblox infinite rotating loop

Tags: loops, rotation, roblox

I am working on doing a health pack for Roblox for my game. the code is complete and it works perfectly, but I want the health pack itself to rotate slowly in a cool way so here is my code tell me what is wrong

```
local healthPack = script.Parent
local healAmount = 30
local cooldown = 5
local canHeal = true

local function handleTouch(otherPart)
    local character = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChild('Humanoid')
    if humanoid and canHeal then
        if game.Workspace.Player1.Humanoid.Health == 100 then

            print("You have enough health")

        else

        canHeal = false

        game.Workspace.HealthPack.Transparency = .75

            local currentHealth = humanoid.Health
            local newHealth = currentHealth + healAmount
            humanoid.Health = newHealth
            wait(cooldown)
            canHeal = true
            game.Workspace.HealthPack.Transparency = 0 

        end
    end
end

healthPack.Touched:connect(handleTouch)


while true do
    local currentRotationX = game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.X
    --local currentRotationX = game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.Y
    local currentRotationZ = game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.Z

    game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.X = currentRotationX + 10
    --game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.Y = currentRotationY + 10  
    game.Workspace.HealthPack.Rotation.Z = currentRotationZ + 10

    wait(.5)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. In order to rotate an object *correctly* (modifying the rotation property usually doesn't do the trick, it's similar to the position property, it conforms to collisions) you must use *CFrame*.

```
local x = 0
while true do
  game.Workspace.HealthPack.CFrame = game.Workspace.HealthPack.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(0, math.rad(x), 0)
  x = x + 1
  wait()
end
```

Fair disclaimer, I haven't worked with RBX.Lua in a while, so this might not be the best way to do it.

Comment: I would recommend looking up CFrame on the ROBLOX Developer Wiki. As a short description, it's a property in all bricks that controls the orientation (rotation) and position of the brick. Rotation is a bit complex, and I would recommend at least some basic knowledge of rudimentary geometry if you want to delve into handling the rotation of CFrames.

Comment: and there is another problem I want it to rotate in an instant speed but your code makes it rotate faster then get slower so here we have a problem

Comment: Do you mean it starts quickly, and then slows down? That sounds like a performance issue, the code cannot execute the spinning at the same rate due to other scripts using execution time. You could fix this by moving the calculation for spinning to a local script, and having the part only exist locally in the player's camera object (if that's still how you work with local parts, I'm not sure if that's still the recommended method).

Comment: so I get it is impossible to get it moving in a constant speed

Comment: That's not true. I would recommend checking the `Script Performance` tab of your ROBLOX Studio client, and checking if one of your other scripts is using too many resources. If some mission-critical script is utilizing too much CPU time, but can't be made more efficient, then I would recommend offloading the rotation script to client-side processing (local scripts).

Answer (score 0):

```
local runService = game:GetService("RunService")

runService.Heartbeat:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Orientation += Vector3.new(0,0.2,0)
end)
```

you could change the y axis (or any other axis) of the part's orientation forever to rotate slowly with runService.Heartbeat (while True do loop but quicker for a smoother rotation).